# get the content of an image object in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the raw data that is created by imagejpeg() in PHP. I need to cache the content since the function generating the image is kind of slow. I know I can provide a 2nd parameter, but that's not what I want.

Thx

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Output Control Functions](http://se.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) to capture the raw data that is normally printed by the function.

In the below example we will store the data originally printed by `imagejpeg` in `$image_data`.

```
ob_start();

  imagejpeg ($img);

  $image_data = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();
```

- [`ob_start`](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) will start buffering of output
- [`ob_get_contents`](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php) will get the current buffer data
- [`ob_end_clean`](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php)` will turn off output buffering and make everything return to normal

---

If you are using a PHP version newer than 5.3 you can add this wrapper function to your library, it will take a callback and return the data that would normally be printed out.

```
function get_output ($callback) {
  ;      ob_start     ();
  ;      $callback    ();
  return ob_get_clean (); // get data and turn off buffering
}

...

$image_data = get_output (
  function () {imagejpeg ($img);}
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using an output buffer like this ->

```
ob_start(); // start a new output buffer
imagejpeg( $newimage, NULL, 100 ); // generate the image
$ImageData = ob_get_contents(); // grab the buffer contents
ob_end_clean; // stop this output buffer
```

Answer (score 0):

I simple hit on google gave me this:

```
ob_start();
ImageJPEG($img);
$data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```